# Execution failed for task ':app:parseDebugLocalResources'

Tags: uinavigationbar

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable

> Failed to parse XML file 'D:\main Project protypes\AndroidUberReamake\app\build\intermediates\packaged_res\debug\layout\nav_header_driver_home.xml'
> Exception is:
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
> at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:339)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130)
> at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:321)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:304)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:309)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:92)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:78)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:66)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:244)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:221)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:204)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:187)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:165)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:124)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:80)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:58)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:181)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:71)
> at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:69)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:47)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:254)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:91)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:281)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:139)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> Caused by: com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceDirectoryParseException: Failed to parse XML file 'D:\main Project protypes\AndroidUberReamake\app\build\intermediates\packaged_res\debug\layout\nav_header_driver_home.xml'
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceDirectoryParser.parseResourceFile(ResourceDirectoryParser.kt:230)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceDirectoryParser.parseResourceDirectory(ResourceDirectoryParser.kt:151)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceDirectoryParser.parseResourceSourceSetDirectory(ResourceDirectoryParser.kt:102)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTaskKt.doFullTaskAction(ParseLibraryResourcesTask.kt:228)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable.run(ParseLibraryResourcesTask.kt:147)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
> at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
> at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
> ... 2 more
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation of a resource with name 'avatar ' and type 'id' failed.'
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.Symbol$Companion.validateSymbol(Symbol.kt:173)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.Symbol$Companion.createSymbol(Symbol.kt:113)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.Symbol$Companion.createSymbol(Symbol.kt:91)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.Symbol$Companion.createSymbol$default(Symbol.kt:85)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceExtraXmlParser.checkForResources(ResourceExtraXmlParser.kt:113)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceExtraXmlParser.parseChild(ResourceExtraXmlParser.kt:88)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceExtraXmlParser.parseChild(ResourceExtraXmlParser.kt:95)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceExtraXmlParser.parseResourceForInlineResources(ResourceExtraXmlParser.kt:69)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.ResourceDirectoryParser.parseResourceFile(ResourceDirectoryParser.kt:227)
> ... 34 more
> Caused by: Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character
> at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergingException$Builder.build(MergingException.java:152)
> at com.android.ide.common.resources.ValueResourceNameValidator.validate(ValueResourceNameValidator.java:48)
> at com.android.ide.common.symbols.Symbol$Companion.validateSymbol(Symbol.kt:171)
> ... 42 more

I tried changing the plugins,build versions and tags but nothing works.